# JavaFx accessing constructor args from initializable

Tags: java, class, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to access values passed to the constructor, in the initialize function. Current, I am passing them to some instance variables, and then accessing them from the initialize function. Is there a better/more concise way of doing this?

```
public class Example implements Initializable{

    private int instanceVariable;

    public Example(int exampleArg) {
        instanceVariable = exampleArg;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println(/* Somehow access exampleArg in the constructor */);
    }
}
```

Comment: There just is no way to do this. For every method/constructor invokation the JVM puts a frame on the stack containing parameters/local variables. Once that method/constructor completes this frame will be dropped and information from this frame will no longer be accessible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the local variables of a method/ constructor such as `exampleArg` in another method but you can access member fields such `instanceVariable`.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I expected. I was hoping there would be another way since I only ever use those variables during initialisation. Thanks anyway!